# ASP dynamically created image, unable to display in web browser control

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I'm currently under the belief it may be to do with the header information but I'm really not too sure. [The image](http://www.lse.co.uk/member-info.asp?nick=mulledwine) on this page is the best example of it that I can give. It will display sometimes in a web browser control, and other times it just plain refuses to. Does anyone have any idea as to why?

The code I'm using to try and grab the image is simply:

```
WebBrowser.Navigate("http://www.lse.co.uk/tools/user/imgChatUsagePie.asp?nick=mulledwine", null, null, "image/gif");
```

It's really hard to ascertain as to what is causing the image to display sometimes and others not as it works completely fine within Chrome. Is this a problem related specifically to the web browser control?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Install [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and capture the traffic for requests made by your application. Is there any difference in the request or response between when the image displays successfully and when it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the server side script checks the ASP Session ID cookie and displays the image depending on some session variable stored on the server.

Try navigating the to the HTML page first, then request that image.

Comment: This is exactly the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the data is a valid image, and sometimes it is not.

But seriously You need to give more information I assume you mean

http://www.lse.co.uk/tools/user/imgChatUsagePie.asp?nick=mulledwine

Maybe post the code you use to generate the image. Is this browser specific. Under what conditions does the pie chart fail to generate. Does the url give an error message when it refuses to display the image etc. I would assume some variable you use to generate the image is null and throws an unhandled exception causing the page to return 500 and some kind of error rather than image data.

If it is really just sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't id recommend using some kind of test suit to keep requesting the image at random images until it fails and then isolate the error message. Selenium or Fiddler may be of some use to isolate the problem.